# Android not able to connect to local xmpp server

Tags: android

I have successfully installed the XMPP sever on my system . I have also installed openfire successfully . I am using this xmpp server for making a chat application. I am trying to connect to this XMPP server through Android Device . I am entering the following detail for connecting to it[image: Setting Dialog]

I am entering my IP address of the system 123.236.42.26 where my xmpp server is running as a host and my port number is 5222.

my code for connecting to xmpp server

```
      public void onClick(View v) {
            String host = getText(R.id.host);
            String port = getText(R.id.port);
            String service = getText(R.id.service);
            String username = getText(R.id.userid);
            String password = getText(R.id.password);

             // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

           try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + 
             connection.getHost());
         } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " +  
         connection.getHost());
              Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
              xmppClient.setConnection(null);
           }
           try {
               connection.login(username, password);
               Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

              // Set the status to available
              Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
             connection.sendPacket(presence);
             xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
          } catch (XMPPException ex) {
             Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
                  Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
                  xmppClient.setConnection(null);
           }
          dismiss();
      }
```

but when i click on ok button my application crashes and when i check the logcat it giving error like

```
06-21 08:01:37.157: E/XMPPClient(4861): [SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to null
06-21 08:01:37.157: E/XMPPClient(4861): 123.236.42.46:5222 Exception: XMPPError 
connecting to 123.236.42.46:5222.; : remote-server-error(502)
06-21 08:01:37.157: E/XMPPClient(4861):   -- caused by: XMPPError connecting to 
123.236.42.46:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to 
123.236.42.46:5222.
06-21 08:01:37.157: E/XMPPClient(4861):   -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 
failed to connect to /123.236.42.46 (port 5222): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection 
timed out)
06-21 08:01:37.217: E/AndroidRuntime(4861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 08:01:37.217: E/AndroidRuntime(4861): Process: org.apache.android.xmpp, PID: 4861
06-21 08:01:37.217: E/AndroidRuntime(4861): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not 
connected to server.
06-21 08:01:37.217: E/AndroidRuntime(4861):     at  
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:229)
```

Please suggest where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is XMPP Client your app? Why are you displaying 192.168.0.1 if you want to connect with 123.236.42.26? Because the last one is no local address. The first one is. Find out the local ip of your server pc with ipconfig.

Comment: Actually I have tried it with first one but giving error

Comment: This one too. So what to do? Please provide the requested info and react on suggestions: what is the lan ip of your server computer? Did you find out with ipconfig? Please explain where you got the second ip from.

Comment: My lan ip address is 192.168.0.1. I had this one with ipconfig and the second one I am getting from online site http://whatismyipaddress.com/   . My XMPP server pasword is root and username is also root. I have tried that one with two but its not working.

Comment: If you are using an Android device and that device is on the same (W)LAN as your server then 192.168.0.1 should work. Your second/external/internet ip address should work too. But as that is the ip address of your router you had to configure your router first to forward port 5222 to  192.168.01:5222. Do you get the same error with both addresses? What is `openfire` ? If it is a firewall then switch it off. Switch temporarily all firewalls off.

Comment: What i see now in your code is that you are trying to connect in an onClick handler. Then your code executes in the main thread. I think you have to place that code in an AsyncTask or Thread. Isn't there a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in the logs?